# How to replace lambda with a method reference for interface methods?

Tags: java, java-8

How to replace lambda with a method reference in interface methods?

```
public abstract interface Job
{
  public abstract String empName();

  public void JobWithDesc(String title)
  {
    setJobValueDesc(title, empName());
  }
}



public final class JobClient {

  private static final Job job;


  static {
    job = () -> ListJob.getName;
  }

  public static final Job getJob() {
    return job;
    }
}
```

wanted to replace this (job = () -> ListJob.getName;) lambda with a reference . Please help me on this

Comment: your code doesn't compile and no you cannot turn  `() -> "EmpApplication"` into a method reference without creating another method. you can create a method as such `private static String getApplication() {
         return "EmpApplication";
     }` which you can then do `job = JobClient::getApplication;`

Comment: Your `abstract interface` doesn't make sense. Interfaces are inherently abstract, and you can only provide a method implementation if you use the `default` keyword.

Comment: What is `ListJob` why not do, `ListJob::getName` ?

Comment: @Aomine actually, you can do it by referring to either `intern` or `toString`

Comment: @Aomine String::toString returns the same String. So you wouldn't really need to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
job = "EmpApplication"::toString;
```

The question, though, is why you want to turn it into a method reference.

It's a simple lambda returning a `String` literal. There is no method being called.

We could wrap `"EmpApplication"` into a static method and refer to it or use an instance method that returns itself.

Comment: @nullpointer I presumed the lambda is correct and the interface is functional. Though, `default` for the second method is missing

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a method:

```
public static String getEmpApp() {
    return "EmpApplication";
}
```

And use it:

```
static {
    job = JobClient::getEmpApp;
}
```

I see no point in doing so, though.

That said, your `Job` interface has compilation errors. `JobWithDesc` method should be either `static` or `default`, and it calls a method - `setJobValueDesc` - not defined anywhere.